# Docker compose: change docker compose file without removing the container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to update the `docker-compose.yml` file for a service of mine to change `restart: "no"` for `restart: unless-stopped`.

I used `restart: "no"` originally to debug the container, but now it's working I had data that I don't won't to erase; so I would like to edit the `docker-compose.yml` file to keep the change reflected in it (for future reference) and apply the change.

Can I just stop the container without removing it and then apply a `docker-compose up`? Or `docker-compose up` is only meant for "fresh created" containers and I have to use another docker command after editing `docker-compose.yml`?

Answer (score 2):

Deleting and recreating containers is extremely routine, and there are many settings you can only change by deleting and recreating a container.  If nothing else you'll have to delete and recreate a container to update the image it runs on, when there is inevitably a bug fix or security update.

You should reconfigure your container to use some sort of volume, either a [named volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) or a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/), to hold your application data.  Anything that's not in a volume *will* get lost.

For this particular change, it looks like the [`docker container update`](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) command can modify the restart policy.  You'll have to find the Docker name of the container from `docker ps`, it will be named something like `directory_service_1`.  But you can't use this command to change the image, environment variables, command, port mappings, or volume mounts; changing any of these things requires deleting and recreating the container.